# C - Free a specific struct inside an array inside a stack

Tags: c, arrays, struct, stack, free

During my stack building I encountered a problem with free an element inside an array in my Pop function.
This is the code:

```
Element Pop(Stack *stackPtr)
{
    Element temp = stackPtr->content[stackPtr->size-1];
    Element* newE = (Element*)realloc(stackPtr->content,(stackPtr->size-1)*sizeof(Element));

    free(stackPtr->content[stackPtr->size-1]);

    stackPtr->content=newE;
    stackPtr->size--;
    return temp;
}
```

And for some reason the `free(stackPtr->content[stackPtr->size-1]);` do an error every time.
Why is that and how do I fix that?
Thanks.

This is the whole code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct 
{
    int kind; // boolean
    int num;
    char ch;
} Element;

typedef struct 
{
    Element *content;
    int size;
} Stack;

void Init(Stack* stackPtr)
{
    stackPtr->content = (Element*)malloc(1*sizeof(Element));
    stackPtr->content[0].kind = 3;
    stackPtr->content[0].ch = 'a';
    stackPtr->content[0].num = -2;
    stackPtr->size = 1;
}

void Push(Stack* stackPtr, Element element)
{
    stackPtr->content = (Element*)realloc(stackPtr->content,((stackPtr->size)+1)*sizeof(Element));
    stackPtr->size++;
    stackPtr->content[stackPtr->size-1] = element;
}

Element Pop(Stack *stackPtr)
{
    Element temp = stackPtr->content[stackPtr->size-1];
    Element* newE = (Element*)realloc(stackPtr->content,(stackPtr->size-1)*sizeof(Element*));

    free(stackPtr->content[stackPtr->size-1]);

    stackPtr->content=newE;
    stackPtr->size--;
    return temp;
}

Element Top(Stack *stackPtr)
{
    return stackPtr->content[stackPtr->size-1];
}
```

Comment: Show `Stack`....and how you pass it.

Comment: Reallocating the whole stack at each pop/push is...sub-optimal. I highly recommend to use a linked list or similar as the underlying data structure.

Comment: My task was making a stack using an array, so I can't use a linked list. I added the whole code to the post.

Comment: But you can avoid reallocation on each pop. Typically you would remember capacity and current size individually, and only realloc when the capacity is severely under or oversized. E.g capacity scaling only on potencies of 2.

Answer (score 0):

Of course this crashes - you just have reallocated the data which `stackPtr->content` was pointing to, so the array access is now invalid.

Since you already reallocated, and you are returning the removed element, that call to `free` is pointless though, and illegal in multiple ways. The memory is already free'd, but not only that, it was never a pointer to begin with.

Also be aware which parameters to `realloc` are valid. If your `Pop` function "removes" the last element, you would try to realloc to a size of zero, which isn't legal.

And you should put in a defensive check anyway, ensure that nobody is trying to pop from an already empty stack.

Comment: Before I reallocated I copied the element to a new element (temp) and then I return temp so I don't get where is the problem. The memory isn't free I reallocated the array and the past element which isn't in the array anymore still exits but we have no access to it.

Comment: @NadavSchneider You have reallocated, but had not assigned it back to `stackPtr->content` yet... And the `free` is still nonsense.

Answer (score -1):

Since content[] is an array of pointers, the realloc should use sizeof(Element*), not sizeof(Element), especially if sizeof(Element) less than sizeof(*). 
Edited to reflect intent of Comments:

```
Element *Pop(Stack *stackPtr)
{
if (stackPtr->size==0) return NULL;
Element temp = stackPtr->content[stackPtr->size-1];
stackPtr->size--;
if (stackPtr->size==0) free(stackPtr->content)
else {   
Element* newE = (Element*)realloc(stackPtr->content,stackPtr->size)*sizeof(Element));
stackPtr->content=newE;
}
Element* rslt = malloc(sizeof(Element);
memcpy(rslt,&temp,sizeof(Element));
return rslt;
}
```

In the using code the pointer returned would need to be free'd separately. I view this as safer than assuming the compiler will copy the auto allocation of temp into the return value, anyways.

Comment: Sorry, you hadn't added the rest of code so I misread things. I thought the stack was an array of pointers to mallocs of Element, to avoid the reuse problem after realloc() the other posters are correct about. Then the free() of the last element would be plausible. The free() should only occur when last element pop'd, as @Ext3h points out, not try to free a subblock each time; the realloc() already did that.

Comment: So do you claim that I don't need free at all? It's not working without free either lol

Comment: Check the new code block; what tweaks are needed for the rest of the code should be straightforward... if Pop() returns null, you need to reinit the stack, not just Push().

Comment: I tried your code. This is the main: https://imgur.com/a/MLhbW in line 131 I changed it to be Element* and then the output is that: https://imgur.com/Jgkf4Ay

Comment: As you can see the pop isn't working very well. It does return the top element but the top element doesn't removed from the stack

Comment: Sorry, I typoed the parens in the realloc, should be:

Comment: Sorry, I typoed the parens in the realloc, should be: `(stackPtr->content, (stackPtr->size*sizeof(Element) ) );` If the same pointer is returned, trying to access the data by a constant array index might still work, but isn't guaranteed. Code should use [--stackPtr->size] as last valid index for non-Pop() access.